# Keycloak - Synchronize some users between two instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api, aws-regions

I'm trying to synchronize some users (by custom attribute) between 2 Keycloak instances, **including credentials**.

The use case:
Keycloak is sitting in AWS, and we want to have a secondary instance on other region, for high availability even in case of AWS region failure.

How can I achieve this using Keycloak API, SPI or other methods?

(We thought even to access Keycloak DB directly and get the data, but it's the last solution and I might miss some data and it will broke the second instance.)

Comment: Are you not running Keycloak with a PostgreSQL database? The solution would seem to be to use RDS for the database and utilize the AWS tools for syncing that data across regions.

Answer (score 0):

I have done all the procedures (not including credentials) using Keycloak REST API and Python. Unfortunately, the repository is private and I could not share the entire solution, but here goes some references/tips to get rid of:

- Examples to list, delete, set properties, query, so on: https://github.com/marcospereirampj/python-keycloak Here you have all examples needed to use the API (and Python).

The only thing I could not take advantage from the Keycloak API is the credential migration. To workaround, I read credentials from the database of the Keycloak source instance. Pretty much like:

```
self.local_kc_user_credentials = pg_obj.load_credentials('public', ['credential', 'user_entity'])
```

where `load_credentials`:

```
    def load_credentials(self, schema, tables):
        """
        Source:
            - https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tutorial-postgresql-python?utm_source=adwords_ppc
        """
        sql_command = "SELECT ue.username, ue.email, c.value, c.salt, c.algorithm, " \
                      "c.hash_iterations FROM {}.{} c INNER JOIN {}.{} " \
                      "ue ON c.user_id = ue.id ORDER BY ue.email".format(schema, tables[0], schema, tables[1])
        logging.info(">>>>>> Loading user credentials...")
        data = pd.read_sql(sql_command, self.conn)
        logging.info(">>>>>>>> Loaded {} registers!".format(len(data)))
        return data
```

So, what you have to do is to find the respectively user in that list and set his credential in the payload:

```
payload['credentials'] = self.load_credential(username)
```

where `load_credential` is:

```
match_user = self.local_kc_user_credentials.loc[self.local_kc_user_credentials['username'] == username]

        if match_user.shape[0] != 0:
            pwd_hash_kc = str(match_user['value'].values[0])
            salt_value = bytes(match_user['salt'].values[0])
            encoded_salt = base64.b64encode(salt_value).decode('ascii')

            payload = [{
                "type": "password",
                "temporary": False,
                "hashedSaltedValue": pwd_hash_kc,
                "salt": encoded_salt,
                "hashIterations": int(match_user['hash_iterations'].values[0]),
                "algorithm": str(match_user['algorithm'].values[0]),
            }]
```

I could not count with Keycloak API to migrate credentials, so, that was the solution applied in my project. Here some references that I have used:

- [Failing to create user with password via Keycloak Rest API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955189/failing-to-create-user-with-password-via-keycloak-rest-api)
- [Convert byte[] to base64 and ASCII in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920799/convert-byte-to-base64-and-ascii-in-python/43923197)
- [How to handle binary data between Python and PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64530062/how-to-handle-binary-data-between-python-and-postgresql)
- [Python Doesn't Derive Same Hashkey For a given password and salt as Keycloak or Online Password Hashers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768600/python-doesnt-derive-same-hashkey-for-a-given-password-and-salt-as-keycloak-or)
- https://tipsfordev.com/migrating-users-from-keycloak-to-ldap-with-passwords-intact